# Any package manager that enforce segregation based on desktop environments available for Ubuntu 22.04 and later?

Tags: package-management, desktop-environments

I'm still using many old hardware machines 10-15 years (Intel CPU's: Atom, Core Duo up to i7 early generations).

In late releases of KDE, Gnome and some other DE's, they started deploying multiple background services which a normal path for modern OS with the current hardware support.

My dilemma comes, when I am using a lite DE (for example Xubuntu and Lubuntu, ..); Then try to install a tool. Even I am usually cautious, I am still making mistakes from time to time. In one case, I was in Xubuntu and installed a KDE tool, in another I install GTK based tool that was relaying on Gnome base. Consequences:

- Large pile of other DE packages get installed.
- Many services get launched and system get slow.
- Cleaning and uninstalling these packages is not always easy.

Currently, I am only relaying on check of dependencies getting installed.

Is there any package manager that check and show hints about compatibility with current desktop environment?

- GUI preferred if there is
- Even, if it is only available for one of the lite DE's
- Minimum feature I am looking for: highlight dependency on GUI frameworks (GTK, Qt ...)
- If offers search option for the source type (deb, snap, appimage), that's even better

Comment: I'm not aware of any GUI tool that does it; but I also install packages usually from terminal, where the install itself (*what will get installed & you're asking for confirmation*) gives all the clues I usually require. If I'm not sure (eg. Lubuntu you mention uses LXQt which is the same Qt5 as used by KDE Plasma, but LXQt doesn't require the KDE Frameworks that KDE Plasma does) I just look up *depends* as you mention anyway (*or just peruse the `--dry-run` option probably more so*). Reversing installs is usually not a problem though (*in my experience*)

Comment: Yeah, that one way to go, additional checkpoint. I may even write script to filter packages to be installed  and present those in my watch list. Thank you for comment.

Comment: 1. Rarely do packages belong to a DE. KDE depends GTK. GIMP, Chromium depend GTK. VirtualBox depends Qt. 2. Those are user services. Run `systemctl --user mask <name>.service` 3. It's as simple as removing the last package and autoremoving. Disable suggests and recommends if you haven't already